# A Vim command to insert a certain piece of text for matching lines unless it is already present

Tags: regex, vim, latex, replace

When editing a LaTeX document, I want to have the `% (fold)` string appended at the end of every line that has a `\begin{‹environment›}` command in it (for any `‹environment›`).

I have tried using the following Vim command:

```
:g/\\begin\{\w+\}/ s/$/\% \(fold\)/
```

but it doubles the `% (fold)` string for the lines where it is already present.

How can I modify the above command to insert `% (fold)` only if it is not already there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just modify the pattern in the `:global` (or `:substitute`) command
to only match the lines that do not end with `% (fold)`:

```
:g/\\begin{\w\+}/ s/\(% (fold)\)\@<!$/% (fold)/
```

or

```
:g/\\begin{\w\+}\(.*% (fold)$\)\@!/ s/$/% (fold)/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:
`:v/% (fold)$/s/\(\\begin.*$\)/\1% (fold)`

That means for every line that does not end with `% (fold)`, search for `\begin` and all the characters until the end and replace it with the search plus the `% (fold)`